# Cómo obtener el ID del autor de un comentario en Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Actualmente estoy trabajando en los comentarios de Wordpress.

Con `$comment_ID` puedo obtener el ID de un comentario, pero mi interés es obtener el ID de la persona que ha realizado el comentario.

He intentado con esto, pero al parecer **`get_user_b`y** no me quiere tomar el email cuando lo paso en una variable. Si lo hago directamente en string todo anda bien.

```
<?php 

    $ue = comment_author_email( $comment_ID ); // Recibir el email del autor del comentario
    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $ue);

    if ( ! empty( $user ) )
    {
        echo $user->ID;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hola Anton, lee [ask] donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tus preguntas. Esta pregunta necesita correcciones para que se pueda resolver y sea de ayuda a otros usuarios: ¿estás usando algún plugin para gestionar los comentarios? ¿qué has intentado hasta el momento? ¿Con qué dificultades te estás encontrando?

Comment: Prueba con 
<?php $author = get_comment_author_email( $comment_ID ); ?>

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias. Nunca imagine que simplemente agregar el **_get** lo haria funcionar.

Comment: @track3r se reabrió la pregunta si te interesa publicar la respuesta